# Branch created by someone else is not visible

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

There is a branch in github that I can access via Eclipse/eGit.  A colleague then created a branch off of that existing branch, but that new branch is not visible to me in Eclipse or from the command line. What do I need to do to make that branch-off-of-a-branch visible to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague needs to [push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) it to Github, then you need to do a [fetch](https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) to get it from Github. Then, if you want to work on that same branch yourself, you need to create a local branch based on it, which, in recent Git versions, can be done simply via [`git checkout <simple branch name>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).

**Update:** So when you have trouble fetching remote refs, you should check that your fetch refspec looks something like `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, or you won't see the whole picture.

Comment: It is in github.  I can view it there via the web interface.

Comment: That means it's pushed. You need to fetch from Github to see it locally.

Comment: I don't know Eclipse, but you don't choose a branch when you fetch. You just fetch. At the command line, you'd use `git fetch` or `git fetch <remote name>` if Github isn't your `origin`. Fetching from a remote downloads the latest stuff from the remote, including any branches that exist there.

Comment: So I fetch and I'm told everything's up to date.

Comment: Then you should already have a local record of the remote branch. It'll show up as a branch called `origin/foo` if `foo` was the branch created and pushed and the Github repo is named `origin`. Now you want to create a local branch called `foo` that tracks `origin/foo`. From the command line, that would be `git checkout foo`, and git would auto-discover `origin/foo` and make it the upstream branch that you'd push changes to.

Comment: Let me correct myself: the *default* fetch behavior is to fetch all changes. If something has changed your defaults, you might not be getting everything. Make sure that when you fetch your fetch refspec is set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: That was it.  The heroku tooling didn't set things up properly.

Comment: Updated. It seems strange that heroku would have settings that mess with your ability to fetch since it uses git as the mechanism for deploying changes...